# Asterisk how to call by names instead of numbers

Tags: alias, asterisk, sip

I haven't found anywhere clear sample how can I setup alphanumeric alias for internal numbers.

For example I am calling now to 504@ip.

How can I make it possible to reach 504 number by john@ip by editing configs?

All extension samples I found have much info about masking and no example of just simple "john" alias configuration. I want asterisk to treat john as 504@ip and kate by 505@other_server_ip. Can I set up that easily on every asterisk server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Asterisk** itself have **no problem** with alfa-numeric numbers in sip or in dialplan.

Just add to dialplan something like this

```
[public];this should be your real public context
exten => john,1,Goto(504,1)
```

However most **webs** like freepbx etc **NOT SUPPORT** that, so you have learn about custom contexts and dialplan.